# calculate cell potential for the voltaic cell where its involving the two cobalt species with Copper

Tags: electrochemistry, electrolysis, reduction-potential

Calculate the cell potential for the voltaic cell that results when the following two half-cells are connected at $\pu{25 ^\circ C}$:

(1) A platinum electrode inserted into a solution of $\pu{0.10 M}$ $\ce{Co^3+}$ and $\pu{0.0010 M}$ $\ce{Co^2+}$

(2) A copper electrode inserted into a solution of $\pu{0.010 M}$ $\ce{Cu^2+}$ ions

> Answer. $\pu{1.66 V}$

how it's calculated?

I know how to calculate the second cell half but what about the first half?

**Edit 1**

will I need more than this equation?

Cathode

$\ce{{Co^{3+}} + e− ⇌ {Co^{2+}}  ->   1.92V}$

**Edit 2 from Nicolas Answer**

$\ce{E=E^0 -0.059*log \frac{[Co^{2 +}]}{[Co^{3 +}]}}$

$\ce{E=1.92 -0.059*log \frac{0.001}{0.1}}$

$\ce{E=2.038}$

Now how to use the Nernst equation again, which concentration I will use for Co?

> I Thought I will use it for the cell, not just half cell which requires two concentrations

**Edit 3**

Applying Nernst to the second half

anode:

$\ce{Cu^{2 +}(aq) + 2e- → Cu(s) ->  +0.34}$

$\ce{E=E^0 - \frac{0.059}{2}*log \frac{1}{[Cu^{2 +}]}}$

$\ce{E=0.34 -\frac{0.059}{2}*log \frac{1}{0.01}}$

$\ce{E=0.281}$

E cell = E cathode - E anode = 2.038 - 0.281 = 1.757

The answer is 1.66 did I make everything right and That's a book's mistake?

**Edit 4**

trying to solve it in one step

Cathode
$\ce{{2Co^{3+}} + 2e− ⇌ {2Co^{2+}}  ->  1.92V}$

Anode :
$\ce{Cu ⇌  Cu^{2 +} + 2e- ->    0.34V}$

Cell:
$\ce{{2Co^{3+}} + Cu ⇌  Cu^{2 +} + {2Co^{2+}} ->    1.58V}$

$\ce{E=E^0 - \frac{0.059}{2}*log \frac{[Co^{2 +}]^2[Cu^{2 +}]}{[Co^{3 +}]^2}}$

$\ce{E=1.58 -\frac{0.059}{2}*log \frac{0.001^2 * 0.01}{0.1^2}}$

E = 1.76

So I think it's a book's mistake written 1.66 instead of 1.76

Comment: **Hint:** Find a half-reaction involving the two cobalt species.

Comment: In both cases (in all cases besides), the principle is the same: one writes the corresponding half-equation of the couple concerned then one establishes its potential using the relation of Nernst

Comment: Is there any link for a question like this?

Comment: Do you know about Nernst's relationship? Otherwise, it might direct you to seek it out and apply it to your half cell.

Comment: Yes I know Nernst's relationship but it requires the concentration of the two half cells

Comment: Start by writing the equation corresponding to the first half-cell then the associated Nernst relation

Comment: I am trying after more searching, does these steps seem right?

Comment: in the statement, you indicate that the 1st half-cell corresponds to a mixture of $ \ce{Co^{2 +}} $ ions and $\ce {Co^{3 +}} $ ions but in your equation guess, you used copper!

Comment: omg sorry, I will start searching again

Comment: will I need more than this equation?

Comment: Reading you, I still have the impression that Nernst's relationship is not very familiar to you: a little tour in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nernst_equation should help you understand how to use it.

Comment: ok I will read about it again

Comment: by the way, you ask how to do for $ \ce {Co} $ except that in your statement it is question of copper for the second half-cell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation noted corresponds well to that of the first half-cell: on the other hand, the potential indicated is not the good one but just that of the standard potential.

The Nernst relation is written $\ce{E=E^0 +0.06*log \frac{[Co^{3 +}]}{[Co^{2 +}]}}$: the potential therefore depends on the concentrations

You can therefore calculate the potential of this half-cell.
You do the same thing with the second to arrive at its potential: from the 2, you can calculate the potential of the cell

Comment: did I solve it right?

Comment: @A.Hany, Your approach is correct. The book may have round off errors.